# Explanation of the Codename One "On Device Web Server"

Tags: codenameone

Two years ago, I read your article: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/on-device-web-server.html

I still remember being intrigued, but then I never went deeper. Today I was thinking about it again and I'd like to understand better.

What programming languages does this local server support? It seems strange to me that it is an equivalent of Apache, IIS, Tomcat or similar... Actually, what can I do with this server? I didn't get that from your blog article.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Whose article? This isn't codenameone support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webserver is currently very simplistic and only serves files. The main use case we needed to attack was that of HTML5 features that won't work when running from a file but would work from a URL.

So it doesn't support a specific language like Java Servlets etc. as it's implemented natively.